# How bad is Error Rates in HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Since a few days ago I'm experiencing slowness in HDD. It is a Transcend HDD with `5400 RPM`. That HDD 3 - 4 years old and `4267 power-on hours` and `1605 power-on count`. I am using `CrystalDiskInfo` software to check the HDD status and currently, it is showing status as `GOOD`. But when I am using the HDD it is very slow. I am very much frustrated now if there is any failure or will be any failure soon or in future. So I would like to know how serious is this problem and is anything wrong with the values shows in the CrystalDiskInfo. I am attaching a CrystalDiskInfo status image. Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

Comment: Any 5400RPM drive is slow, by definition, compared to current requirements. And yours is showing several critical errors indeed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CrystalDiskInfo is labelling the disk as "Good" because it has no bad sectors.

However, the Read Error Rate is 83.

The counter is described as:

> Read Error Rate S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates the rate of hardware
> read errors that occurred when reading data from a disk surface. Any
> value differing from zero means there is a problem with the disk
> surface, read/write heads (including crack on a head, broken head,
> head contamination, head resonance, bad connection to electronics
> module, handling damage). The higher parameter’s value is, the more
> the hard disk failure is possible.
>
> Recommendations
>
> This is a critical parameter. Degradation of this parameter may
> indicate imminent drive failure. Urgent data backup and hardware
> replacement is recommended.

My conclusion: Your disk is aging and replacement is advised before it
fails. The slowness may be caused by read error and retries, which do
manage to finally recover the data (so no unrecoverable errors).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and detailed explanation. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.

Comment: Hi,,, Will you be able to check the values and tell me is this [hdd](https://superuser.com/questions/1662960/why-wd-hdd-has-different-set-of-values-when-comparing-to-other-wd-hdds) good?