# Why WD HDD has different set of values when comparing to other WD HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a newly brought laptop hard disk WD blue 5400 RPM HDD. And today when I replaced this new HDD with a laptop I checked HDD details from CystalDiskInfo and I saw there are differences between values when comparing to my other WD HDDs CrystalDikInfo details. I just need to know why are these Current, Worst and Threshold and other values are different and also if this disk has any issues with the values. And also if this disk is good or not. Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your picture is unreadable. Posting both case would be better. Posting a logfile for each of the two drives would be best.  Bad documentating causes no answer or bad answers.

Comment: These are run-time values because of HDD aging. Therefore you won't find two HDDs that show the same values (may be only if they are both brand new and from the exact identical product branch).

Comment: @r2d3 It would be better to simply post the actual `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` output via [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download), as CrystalDisk's log output contains a lot of nonsense that isn't relevant to most folks.

Comment: You are totally right JW0914. smartctl -a /dev/sdX > mylog.txt is the way that will even avoid needing to post pictures here.  Replace X in sdX by the drive label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk seems fine. It has fewer events than your other disk.

The value of `100` means no events, so nothing much to remark about the
disk, except the "G-Sense Error Rate" which is `85`.

[G-Sense Error Rate](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9126)
is defined as:

> G-sense error rate S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates the number of errors caused by externally-induced shock or vibration.
>
> Recommendations
>
> This parameter is considered informational by the most hardware vendors. Although degradation of this parameter can be an indicator of drive aging and/or potential electromechanical problems, it does not directly indicate imminent drive failure. Regular backup is recommended. Pay closer attention to other parameters and overall drive health.

If you often transport this laptop, it's recommended that you turn it off
for the duration, so the shocks should not affect its functioning.
Usually an SSD is better than an HDD for a laptop, because it has no
moving parts.

In general, the disk is fine, just should be handled with more loving care
;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and detailed explanation. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question as always. But actually about the `G-sense error` I see now it is `80` in `CrystalDiskInfo`. Why it is decrementing. And this is a new HDD and it's only one week I bought it. I have warranty for 2 years. So is this something I need to worry and claim the warranty and get a new one or should I use it? If you can answer this that will be great.

Comment: I think you can ignore it totally. I have looked at my own disk, and it has a large value in there. This is a desktop machine that is not portable, so this is probably just the disk firmware perhaps registering its own head movements. Your disk is fine and in excellent shape.

Comment: Oh then that's great to hear. Thank you very much. Appreciate your help as always :)